# Unable to deserialize Auth.UserData.attributeMap property to Map<String, String>

Tags: map, user, single-sign-on

I'm building a custom Open ID Connect registration handler for a Salesforce community.

I'm receiving a piece of information in the attributeMap of the UserData object. I'm getting the initial value doing: `data.attributeMap.get('key_name')`. The result of that is formatted as:

```
{mykey=aValidSalesforceContactId,mykey2=anothervalueofsomekind}
```

What I'd like to do is map that to a map of `Map<String, String>`, but I can't seem to find anything showing how to do it. I started writing my own bit of code to split the strings and so on, but someone has to have done this before that's a more "standard" way of doing it.

What is the formatting of that data? Is that from an object, or from json to this? It has to be a conversion of something. If I knew what it was, I could go back.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: is this the ref: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#UserInfo ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `deserializeUntyped(String jsonString)` method to deserialize it as a `Map<String, Object>` (well, technically it's just an `Object` but you can cast it).

Alternatively, if you have consistent key-value pairs, you can deserialize it as a class:

```
MyClass results = (MyClass) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

where your class looks something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String mykey1;
    public String mykey2;
    public MyClass(){} //Constructor is irrelevant here
}
```

There is more info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm

Comment: I think this is where i'm confused. Will deserialize work with having an = sign between the key and the value?